# Error while installing selenium library for robot framework in intellij

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, robotframework

Getting the below error while selenium library for robot framework in intellij

python --version
Python 3.13.0a1

robot --version
Robot Framework 6.1.1

pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary

C:\Users\hp>where python
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\python.exe

```
 Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module> 
          main()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main     
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel 
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 105, in uses_msvc
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 223, in try_compile   
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 128, in _compile      
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile        
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize     
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 233, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-s58m6s9a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 190, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Tried to re-install python restarted system after installing python

Comment: Please  try installing the latest [C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)